# Svelte with TypeScript: How to make vscode also display warnings on problems tab

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte

I have a Svelte project with TypeScript support created with:

```sh
npx degit sveltejs/template ts-test
cd ts-test
node script/setupTypeScript.js
npm install
```

and I'm using the [Svelte for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) extension

vscode reports the following warning on mouse hover:

```
(parameter) filter: any
Parameter 'filter' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7044)
```

[image: error is displaye on mouse-hover but not on problems tab]

As you can see, the error is displayed on mouse-hover but not on the problems tab.

Comment: Do you use the [svelte plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JamesBirtles.svelte-vscode)?

Comment: yes, I updated the quesiton to reflect so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually the right behavior. This is a hint, only warnings/errors are shown in the Problems tab. You get the same behavior in a normal TypeScript file.

VSCode only shows errors/warnings/infos in the Problems tab, there is no option to display hints. The "warning" you talk about is actually a hint, so it's not shown in the Problems tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, just tried with `tsc --noemit` and it's the same behaviour. The question would be if there's some way to configure it to also display warnings, and not only errors.

Comment: I updated my answer. What you think is a warning is a hint, that cannot be shown in that VSCode Problems tab.